# Not able to get the value of the input

Tags: javascript, input

I have a form with an input

```
<input type="text" class="class1 class2 class3 email" id="$email" name="$email" required="" value="email@email.com">
```

I am not able to get the value of the input. **Am I missing something?**

```
    val = document.getElementById('$email').value;
    val = document.getElementsByClassName("email").value;
    val = document.getElementsByName("$email").value;
```

**TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is undefined**

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByName` return HTMLCollection object. You need to access with index.

```js
const val = [];
val[0] = document.getElementById('$email').value;
val[1] = document.getElementsByClassName("email")[0].value;
val[2] = document.getElementsByName("$email")[0].value;
console.log(val);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="class1 class2 class3 email" id="$email" name="$email" required="" value="email@email.com">
```

Comment: I am getting: TypeError: document.getElementsByName(...)[0] is undefined.... I am missing something. Dunno what.

Comment: @JozefP. It works. I've edited my post to show the code work.  The problem could be typo. You are using both `$email` and `email`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will retrieve the `value` content of any element by its `Id`. See the last example for `ByClassName`.

https://jsfiddle.net/

`<input type="text" class="class1 class2 class3 email" id="email" name="$email" required="" valu="email@email.com">`

```
var element = document.getElementById("email");

if(element !== null) {
    console.log("Not null.");
  
  var content = element.value;
  console.log(content);
}
else {
    console.log("Null.");
}
```

ByClassName:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("email");

if(element !== null) {
    console.log("Not null.");
  
  var content = element[0].value;
  console.log(content);
}
else {
    console.log("Null.");
}
```